# OAuth validation fails for valid token in wso2 IS 4.6

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have tried to secure rest API by creating the custom handler with wso2 Identity server 4.6, It shows Invalid token even for valid tokens. `(stub.validate(dto).getValid() always false)` But It works well in IS 4.5.What will be the reason ?
Please help..

### log in IS 4.6

```
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,625] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Access Token Request Received with the Client Id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a, Grant Type : password
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,625] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client credentials were available in the cache for client id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,626] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully authenticated the client with client id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,646] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler} -  Token request with Password Grant Type received. Username : admin@carbon.superScope : , Authentication State : true
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,647] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  Access Token info retrieved from the cache and served to client with client id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,647] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Access Token issued to client. client-id=jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a user-name=admin@carbon.super to application=sample
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,721]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-12-31
 09:38:21,721+0530]
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,723] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.TokenValidationHandler} -  Access token identifier is not present in the validation request
[2013-12-31 09:38:21,740]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-12-31
 09:38:21,740+0530]
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.TokenValidationHandler} -  Access token identifier is not present in the validation request
```

### log in IS 4.5

```
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,432] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service}
-  Access Token Request Received with the Client Id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a, Grant Type : password
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,442] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client credentials were available in the cache for client id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,442] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully authenticated the client with client id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,462] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler} -  Token request with Password Grant Type received.
Username : admin@carbon.superScope : , Authentication State : true
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,462] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler} -  Access Token info retrieved from the cache and served to client with client id : jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,462] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Access Token issued to client. client-id=jjTDKDAThDSg_IroxfpC4qjPCR8a user-name=admin@carbon.super to application=sample
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,582]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-12-31 09:48:47,582+0530]
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,582] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2TokenValidationService} -  Token validation request received for : Client Id : nullTokenType : bearer
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,582] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.BearerTokenValidator} -  Started processing token validation request of type : bearer
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,612]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-12-31 09:48:47,612+0530]
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,612] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2TokenValidationService} -  Token validation request received for : Client Id : nullTokenType : bearer
[2013-12-31 09:48:47,612] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.BearerTokenValidator} -  Started processing token validation request of type : bearer
```

Comment: Is any debug/warn/error logs related to this printed on the server console? If not, assuming you are using OAuth2.0, please try enabling logging by adding following line to the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties file:

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2=TRACE

You'll have to restart the server to make this effective.

Comment: Yes,,I did the same and got the following debug message: 

DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.TokenValidationHandler} -  Access token identifier is not present in the validation request

Comment: I have updated the question with the logs in IS 4.5 and 4.6..Please go through.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem with OAuth Mediator in Wso2 ESB 4.8.0 accessing Wso2 Identity Server 4.6.0 via Oauth2 validation web service. With Identity server 4.5.0 it works fine. The mediator code invokes the client stub passing the accessToken as plain string.

The error message returned by validation service is `Access token identifier is not present in the validation request`.

To answer your question you should use the bundle `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub` in version 4.2.2. It defines a class `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.stub.dto.OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO_OAuth2AccessToken` which should be used as a parameter for the `OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO.setAccessToken` method. The dto object can the be used as parameter for the `OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub.validate` method.

Comment: Thanks for the info....I tried with the bundle you mentioned, But i couldn't pass OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO_OAuth2AccessToken object as an argument for OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO.setAccessToken method, It expects a string variable. Please reply

Comment: The older versions of "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub" defined the "setAccessToken(String)" method. Maybe you are still using an old version of the stub not matching the "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server" bundle version. Please make sure you are using 4.2.2.

Comment: As you are working with ESB 4.8.0, Can you please answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800313/rabbitmq-amqp-transport-support-in-wso2-esb-4-8)?

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, OAuth access token are validated by calling `OAuth2TokenValidationService` web service in Identity Server. Could you try out this service using the SOAPUI and see...  WSDL can be found at (`https://{ip}:{port}/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService?wsdl`). Normally this error is generated when access token is not present in the web service request that is sent to the this service.

In request message body, must be as following..

```
        <xsd1:accessToken>
           <xsd1:identifier>35d1538940ce9a1e86c0a287c521d14</xsd1:identifier>
           <xsd1:tokenType>bearer</xsd1:tokenType>
        </xsd1:accessToken>
```

In your code, "dto" object may not have been properly set with identifier value.

Also please find the sample OAuth token validation client code from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/oauth/validation/client/)

Comment: Hi...Asela...
Access token is present in the service,But it expects an identifier value in access token.
I have compared the jar org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth_4.2.2.jar in IS 4.6 and 4.5 and found that access token in IS 4.5 is just a String variable, But in IS 4.6 access token is an object and it expects an identifier value in that object. How can i set the identifier value to the access token????

Comment: Yes..I tried with SOAP UI and this OAuth token validation client https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/oauth/validation/client/  Both works without any issue.  I guess you are trying with the stub class? I saw that "OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO" class contain some inner class that with "OAuth2AccessToken" object. Some time this can cause the issue to not work with generated stub.  http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/4.2.2/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/dto/OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO.java

Comment: Yes,,,,
Here i have created two objects, one outer class object and an inner class object. I could set an identifier value to the OAuth2AccessToken object (ie. inner class object).But now the validate method in stub cannot take the current dto object as an argument.How can i solve this ?