# RabbitMQ AMQP Transport Support in WSO2 ESB 4.8

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport i have gone through this example to get RabbitMQ AMQP transport support in WSO2 ESB 4.8 but i am getting following error during the Creation of  the RabbitMQ Proxy Service.
Unable to generate proxy data from source: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[16,93]Message: The reference to entity 'rabbitmq.server.port' must end with the ';' delimiter. 
any solution ??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin console "complains" about unescaped & (ampersand) character.

If you change the line with endpoint address by replacing **&** with **&amp;** you should be able to save the service and continue your experiments with WSO2 ESB and RabbitMQ.

Example entry:

```
<address uri="rabbitmq://AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue2&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange2"/>
```